# Best REST practice for responce "GET" method status?

Tags: rest

I didn't find useful information about which methods status is correct for absent object in db.

For example I have deleted user with id = 1, but someone try to get it's information thought GET method with query params id=1.

Which status will be right: 404, 204, 400,406 or 410?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I didn't find useful information about which methods status is correct for absent object in db.

Yup, that's right - HTTP status codes don't tell you anything about rows in a database, what they tell you about are documents ( "resources" ) in a document store.

More precisely, the HTTP status code is metadata that tells general purpose components (like a web browser, or a cache) what's in the message-body of the response.

Depending on what document you put into the message-body, the appropriate status code could be any of:

- 200
- 404
- 410

200 announce that the message-body is a document (more broadly, a current representation of the resource).  404 and 410 (and all 4xx and 5xx status codes) announce that the message-body is a representation of the explanation of the error.

[404](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4) indicates that the document identified by the effective target uri of the request doesn't exist right now, but it might exist later; you can attach caching metadata to communicate when the might check again.

[410](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.9) indicates that the document identified by the effective target uri of the request doesn't exist right now, and that condition is likely permanent.  That permanence implies that clients can delete bookmarks, and remote links to the document should be removed, and so on.

If you recycle ids, or if deletes ids can be restored, then 410 isn't an appropriate choice.

---

In some APIs, resources have current representations even when there is no matching information in the database.

In other words, the current representation of the resource might be an empty document

```
200 OK HTTP/2
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 0
```

or it could be a null object

```
200 OK HTTP/2
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 4

null
```

or it could be an empty list

```
200 OK HTTP/2
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 2

[]
```

or an empty object

```
200 OK HTTP/2
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 2

{}
```

or a meme

```
200 OK HTTP/2
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 36

This space intentionally left blank.
```

The status code to use follows from the decision to use a sort of "default" representation of our document when there is no specific information available.

The more common decision, of course, is to choose not to provide default representations, but instead announce that the client has made a mistake (in which case the 4xx class of status code is the correct starting point).

---

> Isn't it write to return 204(NO CONTENT) status or something similar? 'Cause I think 200 is not fully informative status

Maybe - there's some ambiguity in the HTTP standard, and because of that ambiguity I tend to be biased against 204 (today; if you look up some of my older answers, I was much likely to try 204 in the past).

[RFC 7231, Section 6.3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1)

> Aside from responses to CONNECT, a 200 response always has a payload, though an origin server MAY generate a payload body of zero length. If no payload is desired, an origin server ought to send 204 (No Content) instead.

So we have two different ways to send zero bytes of data back to the client; either 200 with [Content-Length](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3.2) set to zero, or 204.

Are those two things the same?

The answer seems to be "not quite"; there's a subtle difference documented in [section 6.3.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.5)

> The 204 response allows a server to indicate that the action has been successfully applied to the target resource, while implying that the user agent does not need to traverse away from its current "document view" (if any).

Now, think about that in the context of a web browser.  If I click a link that points to an empty file, a 200 response would mean that the browser would traverse away from the current "document view" to show me the empty file.  But the language of 204 suggests that instead the browser should stay put, and just indicate that the empty file was successfully downloaded.

Note: I haven't done any experiments to see if browsers *do* act that way; my only claim is that staying in place is the specified behavior.

My reading of the specification is that 204 is designed to support a use case that only arises in the context of *unsafe* actions, like PUT.  You can see hints of that as far back as [HTTP/1.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-9.2)

> This response is primarily intended to allow input for scripts or other actions to take place without causing a change to the user agent's active document view. The response may include new metainformation in the form of entity headers, which should apply to the document currently in the user agent's active view.

In short, responding with a 204 to a GET request is placing a bet that the authors of general purpose components have interpreted an ambiguous part of the specification the same way that you do -- and I don't like that bet at all.  Much more reliable to use the well understood 200 response, and avoid the unnecessary ambiguity.

Comment: I asked about info that had been deleted by API or didn't exist at all. Then it was getting by a field on a method that return details. Isn't it write to return 204(NO CONTENT) status or something similar? 'Cause I think 200 is not fully informative status.

Comment: I've added a chapter to explain why _I_ wouldn't use 204 here.